# Is there a way of determining how much GPU memory is in use by TensorFlow?

Tags: gpu, tensorflow

Tensorflow tends to preallocate the entire available memory on it's GPUs. For debugging, is there a way of telling how much of that memory is actually in use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(1) There is some limited support with [Timeline](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/client/timeline.py) for logging memory allocations. Here is an example for its usage:

```
    run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
    run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
    summary, _ = sess.run([merged, train_step],
                          feed_dict=feed_dict(True),
                          options=run_options,
                          run_metadata=run_metadata)
    train_writer.add_run_metadata(run_metadata, 'step%03d' % i)
    train_writer.add_summary(summary, i)
    print('Adding run metadata for', i)
    tl = timeline.Timeline(run_metadata.step_stats)
    print(tl.generate_chrome_trace_format(show_memory=True))
    trace_file = tf.gfile.Open(name='timeline', mode='w')
    trace_file.write(tl.generate_chrome_trace_format(show_memory=True))
```

You can give this code a try with the MNIST example ([mnist with summaries](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py))

This will generate a tracing file named timeline, which you can open with chrome://tracing. Note that this only gives an approximated GPU memory usage statistics. It basically simulated a GPU execution, but doesn't have access to the full graph metadata. It also can't know how many variables have been assigned to the GPU.

(2) For a very coarse measure of GPU memory usage, nvidia-smi will show the total device memory usage at the time you run the command.

nvprof can show the on-chip shared memory usage and register usage at the CUDA kernel level, but doesn't show the global/device memory usage.

Here is an example command: nvprof --print-gpu-trace matrixMul

And more details here:
http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/#abstract

Comment: From within chrome://tracing where can you see the total device allocation?

Answer (score 9):

Here's a practical solution that worked well for me:

Disable GPU memory pre-allocation using TF session configuration:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()  
config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True  
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

run **nvidia-smi -l** (or some other utility) to monitor GPU memory consumption.

Step through your code with the debugger until you see the unexpected GPU memory consumption.

Comment: This should work in TF2, too - see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/experimental/set_memory_growth

Answer (score 7):

There's some code in `tensorflow.contrib.memory_stats` that will help with this:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.memory_stats.python.ops.memory_stats_ops import BytesInUse
with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):  # Replace with device you are interested in
  bytes_in_use = BytesInUse()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(bytes_in_use))
```

Comment: I think this is gone in TF2, compare https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40383

Answer (score 2):

The TensorFlow profiler has improved memory timeline that is based on real gpu memory allocator information
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/core/profiler#visualize-time-and-memory

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: The link was possibly pointing to: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler#memory_profile_tool

Answer (score 0):

```
tf.config.experimental.get_memory_info('GPU:0')
```

Currently returns the following keys:

```
'current': The current memory used by the device, in bytes.
'peak': The peak memory used by the device across the run of the program, in bytes.
```

Answer (score 0):

as @V.M previously mentioned, a solution that works well is using: `tf.config.experimental.get_memory_info('DEVICE_NAME')`

This function returns a dictionary with two keys:

- **'current'**: The current memory used by the device, in bytes
- **'peak'**: The peak memory used by the device across the run of the program, in bytes.
  The value of these keys is the ACTUAL memory used not the allocated one that is returned by nvidia-smi.

In reality, for GPUs, TensorFlow will allocate all the memory by default rendering using **nvidia-smi** to check for the used memory in your code useless. Even if, `tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth` is set to true, Tensorflow will no more allocate the whole available memory but is going to remain in allocating **more memory than the one is used** and in a **discrete manner**, i.e. allocates 4589MiB then 8717MiB then 16943MiB then 30651 MiB, etc.

A small note concerning the `get_memory_info()` is that it **doesn't return correct values if used in a `tf.function()` decorated function**. Thus, the peak key shall be used after executing `tf.function()` decorated function to determine the peak memory used.

For **older versions** of Tensorflow, `tf.config.experimental.get_memory_usage('DEVICE_NAME')` was the only available function and only returned the used memory (no option for determining the peak memory).

Final note, you can also consider the **Tensorflow Profiler available with Tensorboard** as @Peter Mentioned.

Hope this helps :)