# Tensorflow slow in extracting pool3 features from a retrained model

Tags: tensorflow

I used the retrain code to train the final layer of the Inception model on my own images. But on my CPU machine, it is taking almost 0.5-0.8 second to extract the pool3 features.

```
pool3 = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('pool_3:0')
pf = sess.run(pool3, {png_data: imgBuffer.getvalue()})
```

The above lines of code take all the time. Is it because of my CPU memory? Any way to make it faster?

Comment: Was it faster with the unmodified code (i.e. without retraining)?

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow uses lazy evaluation; basically all nodes in graph are evaluated on a need basis at sess.run().

This is why you noticed most of time is spent by sess.run and it is not that pool3 in particular is more expensive

You can use [Timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36123740/is-there-a-way-of-determining-how-much-gpu-memory-is-in-use-by-tensorflow/37931964#37931964) to find detailed time breakdown.